# Quitting out of a function while not quitting the program Python

Tags: python-2.7

In my current Python 2.7 project I begin with reading in a file with data, which is a separate function, but if something goes wrong during this process of reading the data I want the function to stop, and the user to "try again", it looks something like this:

```
def main():
ok = False
while not ok:
  file = raw_input();
  FileisOk = readFile(file)
  if FileisOk
    ok = True

def readFile(file):
  try:
    open(file, "r")
  except IOError:
    print "Error message"
    return False
    #stop function
```

So once something goes wrong I want to return to the main function, and let the user enter a different file, but how do I quit readFile and return to main?

Comment: looks like this code will do exactly what you want. "return False" exits the readFile funciton and the "while" loop continues

Comment: BTW you can shorten three lines `FileisOk = readFile(file)/  if FileisOk/
    ok = True`
to one line `ok = readFile(file) `